# How to get post_meta from shortcode in post_meta?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

My pages' content is saved in blocks which are saved in `post_meta` instances. There are `shortcodes` rendered from those blocks *(`post_meta`s)*. It is easy to get the current `$post->ID` from the `global $post`, but how to get the `post_meta` `ID` within the shortcode callback?

```php
add_shortcode("my_shortcode", "do_my_shortcode"));

function do_my_shortcode($attrs, $content = null)
    {
        global $post;
        // this shortcode is executing from one of the following $post_metas:
        $post_metas = get_post_custom($post->ID);

        $post_meta_id = ? // How to get current post_meta id where this shortcode comes from?

        return '<div class="my-shortcode-content" data-postmetaid="'. $post_meta_id .'">My shortcode content!</div>';
    }
```

Comment: get_post_custom() will return an array of key=>pair values. The example in Codex illustrates how to foreach through the returned values.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide attribute for shortcode with meta key.
Something like this:

```
    function get_mid_by_key( $post_id, $meta_key ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $mid = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("SELECT meta_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE post_id = %d AND meta_key = %s", $post_id, $meta_key) );
        if( $mid != '' )
       return (int) $mid;

       return false;
   }

    add_shortcode("my_shortcode", "do_my_shortcode"));

    function do_my_shortcode($attrs, $content = null) {
        global $post;
        
        $a = shortcode_atts( array(
            'meta-key' => '',
        ), $atts );

        $post_meta_id = get_mid_by_key( $post->ID, esc_attr($a['meta-key']) );

        return '<div class="my-shortcode-content" data-postmetaid="'. $post_meta_id .'">My shortcode content!</div>';
    }
```

after that you use your shortcode in some way:

```
[my_shortcode meta-key="somemetakey"]
```

But you can just use shortcode attribute for direct access to meta data, without getting meta id(without function `get_mid_by_key`).